# Unable to open files with a specific macOS application via Python

Tags: python, macos, subprocess, popen

I have a very simple Python script that is used to open a file with an app. However, everytime the script runs it returns the error `[Errno 2] No such file or directory` even though I pass in an absolute path.

```
import subprocess

def open_file(file):
    subprocess.Popen(['open -a /Applications/MyEditor.app', {file}])
```

`file` is an absolute path to the item (e.g., `/Users/mteg/Downloads/plans.pdf`).

I can run the command `open -a /Applications/MyEditor.app /Users/mteg/Downloads/plans.pdf` in Terminal successfully so I'm not sure why it isn't working inside the script. I also tried using `subprocess.call` and `subprocess.check_call` with the same results.

The files that will be passed-in are not always going to have an application associated with it so I want a specific app to open them.

What am I missing?

Comment: You haven't tokenized your command properly. Try `subprocess.Popen(['open', '-a' '/Applications/MyEditor.app', file])`. See also the the pieces about using `shlex.split()` in the documentation of the `subprocess` module.

Comment: Thank you so much. This was driving me crazy